# Set a default sheet (tab) when opening a qlikview file

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

How to set a default sheet (tab) when opening a qlikview file?

I have multiple tabs and would like the document to always open on a specific tab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In QlikView go to

> Settings > Document Properties
>
> Triggers (tab) > In Document Event Triggers choose `OnOpen` > Add Action(s)
>
> Add > Layout > Activate Sheet > Ok > Add in the Sheet ID.

You can find the sheet ID by going to the relevant sheet then `Settings > Sheet Properties` and it is in the top right corner.